# Why return type is not inferred?

Tags: typescript

The generic return type `R` should be inferred as `string`, but it's instead `unknown`. Why and how to make it to be inferred correctly?

```
function call<Args extends any[], R, F extends ((...args: Args) => R)>(
  fn: F, ...args: Args
): R {
  return fn(...args)
}

function some<T>(a: T[]): string { return "" }

let v = call(some, [1]) // => inferred type of v is unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReturnType<F>` as the return type of your function to infer the type from the passed function instead of using the `R` generic

```
function call<Args extends any[], F extends ((...args: Args) => any)>(
  fn: F, ...args: Args
): ReturnType<F> {
  return fn(...args)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQHgIICcDmAzogKYAeUJYAJsSmAJ4DaAugDSIBipFVtiACgEA6USgKEAXIjxEAlIgC8APkT0Gc5QIBQiRMDDTOHUcPFFpswtrnSASiSghcYACoMADiUydVAb11EXEdnJAMRMQk5bQBfbW1QSFgEREI4AFtvVy0UaVdWW1SoXBgwfEQ-IJCXRAAiWsQ47TRHRAA3JWR0NAE0zI4mAEYWaIB6Ub0APQB%20IA)